# phpdoc run in batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, phpdoc

Does anybody know how to use "phpdoc run" in a Windows batch file? If I run:

```
..more lines..

phpdoc run --target %TARGET% --directory %SOURCE% --title "Some title"
exit
```

The batch file stops execution just after running the phpdoc command.

exit is never executed!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely phpdoc is itself a batch. In this case it must be invoked with [`call`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/call.mspx?mfr=true):

> Calls one batch program from another without stopping the parent batch program.

```
..more lines..

call phpdoc run --target %TARGET% --directory %SOURCE% --title "Some title"
exit
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks